# Spring MVC PathVariable truncate issue

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, url, path-variables

The last @PathVariable in the URL truncates the value passed after the . (dot).
which i **fixed** using this

```
@Bean
public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() {
    RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping = super.requestMappingHandlerMapping();
    handlerMapping.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
    handlerMapping.setUseTrailingSlashMatch(false);
    return handlerMapping;
}
```

But now my path is truncated after `#`

Request I am hitting : `http://localhost:8290/dataengine/api/program/ff8080815ff282bd016092e003f00004/customer/username/chandra@#12`

after debug I am getting`http://localhost:8290/dataengine/api/program/ff8080815ff282bd016092e003f00004/customer/username/chandra@`

What Can i do for this `#` ?

Comment: If it's really supposed to be part of the URL, it must be url-encoded (as everything inside a URL). If it's just a regular anchor reference, it's perfectly normal that it's not part of the URL: that's used by the browser to scroll to the anchor named 12.

Comment: @JBNizet I understand . But is there any way where I can stop it from truncating as I did for .(dot) operator

Comment: your request mapping should be like this: `http://localhost:8290/dataengine/api/program/ff8080815ff282bd016092e003f00004/customer/username/{username:.+}`

Comment: @MuddassirRahman have you url-encoded the path parameter? That's the way.

Comment: @HadiJ that regex works for dot(.) character not for hash(#).